# typoscript get uid of page

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.x

Hi I have the following script to get the subpages and print some info from them on parent page as a teaser.

```
lib.unterseiten = CONTENT
lib.unterseiten {
  table = pages
  select {
    pidInList.field = 43
    orderBy = sorting
  }

  renderObj = COA
  renderObj.wrap = <div class='col-md-3'>|</div>
  renderObj {
    10 = TEXT
    10.field = title
    10.wrap = <h2>|</h2>
    20 = CONTENT
    20 {
      table = tt_content
      select {
        pidInList.field = uid
        orderBy = sorting
      }

      renderObj = COA
      renderObj {

        #Bild auslesen
        30 = FILES
        30 {
          maxItems = 1
          references {
            table = tt_content
            uid.data = field:uid
            fieldName = image
            maxItems = 1
          }

          renderObj = IMAGE
          renderObj.file.import.data = file:current:uid
          renderObj.file.treatIdAsReference = 1
          renderObj.wrap = <div class="thumbnail bild">|</div>
          renderObj.stdWrap.maxItems = 1
        }

        40 = TEXT
        40.field = uid
        40.wrap = <a href="/index.php?id=|" class="btn btn-primary">Mehr infos</a>
      }
    }

  }
}

page.20.marks.kumulierterInhalt < lib.unterseiten
```

my issue is I want to add a link at the end ... but the uid I can access is the uid of the content element not of the subpage?

what is my fail in this case?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the ID of the page where the tt_content content is, you can just use the `pid` field instead of `uid`; but the link itself is built in a wrong way; you should better use the [typolink](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Typolink.html) function

I will write here the relevant part of your code:

```
    40 = TEXT
    40.value = Mehr Infos
    40.typolink.ATagParams = class="btn btn-primary"
    40.typolink.parameter.data  = field:pid
```